# Why is only one of my print() repeating itself?

Tags: python

I am having an issue with one of my print statements repeating itself twice on the console. I have tried multiple methods of implementing it through attempted research on SOF and Google, but no luck. Going 2 hours into it and cannot find an explanation.

All my other print statements are functioning correctly by printing once except this one:

```
elif ext[5] in file and ext[4] in file:
        print('application/pdf')
```

This is the entire code:

```
file = input('File name: ').casefold()
ext = ('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.pdf', '.txt', '.zip', '.bin', 'myfile')


for i in range(4):
   if ext[i] in file:
        if ext[1] in file:
            print('image/jpeg')
        else:
            print('image/' + ext[i].replace('.', ''))

for i in range(4, 9):
    if ext[i] in file:
        if ext[7] in file or ext[8] in file:
            print('application/octet-stream')
        elif ext[5] in file and ext[4] in file:
            print('application/pdf')
        elif ext[5] in file:
            print('text/' + file.replace(ext[i], ''))
        else:
            print('application/' + ext[i].replace('.', ''))
```

Comment: elif ext[5] in file or ext[4] in file:

Comment: I'm confused because you wrote the line `if ext[7] in file or ext[8] in file` which is correct, but then on the next line you use an `and` instead of an `or`, which means you only print if `file` contains both `'.txt'` _and_ `'.pdf'`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's printing twice because the appropriate conditions are met on iterations `4` and `5`.  There's no reason at all to do this in an iteration in the first place, though; you should be able to simply remove the entire `for` loop and get the desired result:

```
if ext[7] in file or ext[8] in file:
    print('application/octet-stream')
elif ext[5] in file and ext[4] in file:
    print('application/pdf')
elif ext[5] in file:
    print('text/' + file.replace(ext[i], ''))
else:
    print('application/' + ext[i].replace('.', ''))
```